# parametric plot using matplotlib Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy, parametric-equations

I would like to write a program which draw parametric plot. I have to use matplotlib and sympy with n steps, n is the number of segments approximating the curve. I have a problem with using n. I put a program that doesn't use n and library matplotlib.

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.plotting import plot_parametric
import math

def param(x,y,t,a,b,n):
    t = Symbol('t')
    return plot_parametric(x,y,(t,a,b))

t = Symbol('t')
x=cos(t)
y=sin(t)
n=100
a=0
b=2*pi
plot_parametric(x,y,(t,0,2*pi),n)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the number of points, you need to change the parameter `adaptive` to `False` and set `nb_of_points`. See [the docs](https://docs.sympy.org/1.5.1/modules/plotting.html#sympy.plotting.plot.plot_parametric) for more details and more parameters.

Default, `adaptive` is set to `True` in which case `nb_of_points` is ignored. When `adaptive` is used, the algorithm calculates more points where the curve changes a lot and less where it changes little.

To draw a circle with 20 points (there will be 19 segments):

```
plot_parametric(x, y, (t, 0, 2 * pi), nb_of_points=20, adaptive=False)
```